# Cannot modify Derived that was static_pointer_cast from a vector<shared_ptr<Base>>

Tags: c++, pointers

The title describes the situation, but the underlying problem might be something completely different.

I am trying to make a simple ECS game engine. I have a bunch of entities where each one contains a `vector<shared_ptr<Component>>`. `Component` is the base class for all the derived components.

During the game loop i have different `System`s that update entities with certain components. The way I get the correct component for the system is with the following function

```
        template <typename T> 
        inline T& GetComponent(std::uint32_t type)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Component> baseComponent = this->components[this->typeToIndexMap[type]];
            std::shared_ptr<T> component = std::static_pointer_cast<T>(baseComponent);
            return *(component.get());
        }
```

The issue is that when I try to modify the component in the system  (`inputComponent.lastX = 5.f;`) it does not work. The next frame the values are the same. I am guessing that there happens some kind of cutoff because i am storing `Component` but am not sure how to solve this. Any ideas if that is actually the case and how I can solve it ?

Edit : Additional info

Entity holds components in a `vector<shared_ptr<Component>>`

Adding a Component

```
void Entity::AddComponent(std::shared_ptr<Component> component)
{
    this->components.push_back(component);
    this->componentBitset = this->componentBitset | component->GetComponentType();
    this->typeToIndexMap[component->GetComponentType()] = this->components.size() - 1;
}
```

Component Creation

```
std::shared_ptr<InputComponent> inputComponent = std::make_shared<InputComponent>(InputComponent());
entity->AddComponent(inputComponent);
```

**Component Structure**

```
class Component
{
public:
    // Constructor / Destructor
    Component(std::uint32_t type);
    ~Component();
    std::uint32_t GetComponentType();

private:
    std::uint32_t type;
};
```

Input Component

```
class InputComponent : public Component
{
    public:
        InputComponent();
        ~InputComponent();

        double lastX;
        double lastY;
};
```

Finally we have the system

```
void InputSystem::Update(GLFWwindow* window, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>>& entities)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
    {
        if (entities[i]->IsEligibleForSystem(this->primaryBitset))
        {
            InputComponent component = entities[i]->GetComponent<InputComponent>(ComponentType::Input);
            double x, y;
            glfwGetCursorPos(window, &x, &y);
            // some other things are happening here
            component.lastX = x;
            component.lastY = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Component` a virtual base class? Also _"it does not work."_ isn't a useful problem description.

Comment: it does not have any virtual methods as i am storing only data in there. For the second part, checkout the continuation :)

Comment: You probably have a [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: In order for someone helping you out post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: Could you post how components get created, and the Component class definition?

Comment: just posted the update, thank you for the help and let me know if adding anything else would be of help!

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ said, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think that your problem is here: `InputComponent component = entities[i]->GetComponent<InputComponent>(ComponentType::Input);`. You actually gets the `InputComponent` by value. Try to change `GetComponent` so it will return `T*`, and thee first line I mentioned here change to `InputComponent *component`.

Comment: @KorelK will try it out now

Comment: Worked? Or that you found another problem and solved it?

Comment: @KorelK yep, that worked. It is weird cause i thought that the GetComponent method returns a reference and not a copy. Add an answer and ill accept it :)

Comment: @BenVoigt you are right, i'll update it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
InputComponent component = entities[i]->GetComponent<InputComponent>(ComponentType::Input);
```

You actually gets the `InputComponent` by value. Try to change `GetComponent` so it will return `T*`, and the first line I mentioned here change to:

```
InputComponent *component = entities[i]->GetComponent<InputComponent>(ComponentType::Input);
```